# Log file is not created when i run my runnable jar

Tags: java, log4j

I have used logging in an desktop application using log4j but when i export that utility as a runnable jar then the log file is not created when i run this jar. Below is my log4j.properties file. please tell me what i am missing.

```
# Log levels
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CONSOLE,R
# Appender Configuration
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
# Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# Path and file name to store the log file
log4j.appender.R.File=D:/myapp/mylog.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=200KB
# Number of backup files
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=2
# Layout for Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %c - %p - %m%n
```

Comment: Excuse me for asking the obvious, but have you opened your jar and made sure your log4j.properties is included (at the root level)?

Comment: Do you have `log4j.properties` in your classpath?
Do you have log4j library in your classpath?

Comment: yes i have it in my class path

Answer (score 0):

## Direct log messages to a log file

```
log4j.appender.R.File=C:\\loging.log
```

Follow this tutorial to learn more about log4j usage:

http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/